# Reference repeated named css grid rows

Tags: html, css, css-grid

**TLDR;** This works, but to add another person & their answer, I have to add 4 more nth-child selectors & specify the particular `grid-row-start`s. I want to have an `even` selector and an `odd` selector which handles any number of rows. I can change the html if need be.

I have a grid which shows a person's name, their image, and a body of text. The first row should show the name & image on the right hand side. 2nd row on the left side. And should alternate every row, as shown in this code snippet.

Each 4 nth-child selectors handles one person. For each person listed, I have to write another 4 nth-child selectors. I'd like to make this dynamic, so that I can write an `evens` child selector and an `odds` child selector...

I tried using named-rows, but then the 3rd person moves up to the first two rows, instead of going into the next-named row.

Can I use named rows in a repeatable fashion, or otherwise make the number of rows totally dynamic?

My current solution would be to just list like... 60 nth-child selectors to cover up to 15 persons & just... have my css bloated in that way. Or to put grid-row-start directly on the html elements (which I can do on the server, but I don't want to)

```css
.CandidateAnswers {
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 5fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
        "name blank rev_name"
        "image description rev_image";
    justify-items:center;
    /*grid-template-rows:
        repeat(20,
            [row-name] auto
            [row-detail] auto
            [row-name-rev] auto
            [row-detail-rev] auto
        );*/
}


.CandidateAnswers *:nth-child(1){
    grid-column-start: 3;
    grid-row-start: 1;
}
.CandidateAnswers *:nth-child(2){
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: span 2;
    grid-row-start: 1;
}
.CandidateAnswers *:nth-child(3){
    grid-column-start: 3;
    grid-row-start: 2;
}
.CandidateAnswers *:nth-child(4){
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: span 2;
    grid-row-start: 2;
}

.CandidateAnswers *:nth-child(5){
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-row-start: 3;
}
.CandidateAnswers *:nth-child(6){
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: span 2;
    grid-row-start: 3;
}
.CandidateAnswers *:nth-child(7){
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-row-start: 4;
}
.CandidateAnswers *:nth-child(8){
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: span 2;
    grid-row-start: 4;
}
.CandidateAnswers *:nth-child(9){
    grid-column-start: 3;
    grid-row-start: 5;
}
.CandidateAnswers *:nth-child(10){
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: span 2;
    grid-row-start: 5;
}
.CandidateAnswers *:nth-child(11){
    grid-column-start: 3;
    grid-row-start: 6;
}
.CandidateAnswers *:nth-child(12){
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: span 2;
    grid-row-start: 6;
}
```

```html
<div class="CandidateAnswers">
    <h3>Person 1</h3>
    <span></span>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1mHu.jpg" alt="Person 1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor &amp; stuff blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
    
    <h3>Person 2</h3>
    <span></span>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1mHu.jpg" alt="person 2">
    <p>I'm a person who does persony things and I'm a people and who knows maybe we'll one day be friends</p>
    
    <h3>Person 3</h3>
    <span></span>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1mHu.jpg" alt="Person 3">
    <p>I also am here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Try using the `n` feature, like `4n + 2` etc.

Comment: And perhaps use column flow

Comment: I tried selectors like `:nth-child(1n)`, `nth-child(2n)`, `nth-child(2n+5)` etc... Then I'd put `grid-row: row-name`... & the 3rd person appears on top of the first person (rows 1 & 2), instead of going into rows 5 & 6

Comment: Empty span because I'm still learning grid & when I was playing with it yesterday, that's how I got it to fill the empty space. S'pose I should take 'em out now

Comment: Thanks, the `grid-auto-flow: column` fixed it. I also had to fix my `nth-child` selectors, but without `grid-auto-flow: column`, everything gets bungled.

Comment: My first inclination was to wrap each record in a `div`, but then I couldn't get things to line up correctly & I thought "oh, subgrid"... but that doesn't appear to be well supported yet.

Comment: why you have an empty span?

Answer (score 1):

I kept the same html, added `grid-auto-flow:column;`, removed `grid-row-start`, and removed named areas.

Then I got my `nth-child` selectors right, thanks to mdn's [nth-child docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

```css
.CandidateAnswers {
    display:grid;
    justify-items:center;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.CandidateAnswers *:nth-child(8n-3){
    grid-column-start: 3;
}
.CandidateAnswers *:nth-child(8n-2){
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: span 2;
}
.CandidateAnswers *:nth-child(8n-1){
    grid-column-start: 3;
}
.CandidateAnswers *:nth-child(8n){
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: span 2;
}

.CandidateAnswers *:nth-child(8n+1){
    grid-column-start: 1;
}
.CandidateAnswers *:nth-child(8n+2){
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: span 2;
}
.CandidateAnswers *:nth-child(8n+3){
    grid-column-start: 1;
}
.CandidateAnswers *:nth-child(8n+4){
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: span 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize your code like below:

```css
.CandidateAnswers {
    display:grid;
    grid-auto-flow:dense;
    grid-auto-columns:1fr; /* make all columns equal */
}

h3 {
  grid-column:span 4;  /* this will create 4 columns */
  width:25%; /* take the width of only 1 column*/
  text-align:center;
}
p {
  grid-column:span 3; /* take 3 columns */
  width:66.66%;  /* take the width of only 2 column*/
}

h3:nth-child(6n + 1),
p:nth-child(6n + 3){
  margin-left:auto; /* push to the right  */
}

img {
  margin:auto;
}
img:nth-child(6n + 2){
   grid-column:4;
}
img:nth-child(6n + 5){
   grid-column:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="CandidateAnswers">
    <h3>Person 1</h3>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1mHu.jpg" alt="Person 1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor &amp; stuff blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
    
    <h3>Person 2</h3>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1mHu.jpg" alt="person 2">
    <p>I'm a person who does persony things and I'm a people and who knows maybe we'll one day be friends</p>
    
    <h3>Person 3</h3>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1mHu.jpg" alt="Person 3">
    <p>I also am here</p>
</div>
```